# Delay or block windows hibernation/shutdown

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7

I am currently trying to create an application to delay the suspension or hibernation of a computer so I can gracefully shutdown an application prior to suspension. Thus far I can trigger the event using the "SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged" event handler though I am unable to delay or even block the sleep timer on my PC.

Existing code:

```
void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Mode == PowerModes.Suspend)
    {
        //delay
        //graceful shutdown

    }
```

The event does trigger and the application begins though not enough time is assigned to the application to run work correctly.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can only politely ask windows to delay shutting down, if your program blocks for too long, windows will give the user the option of forcibly terminating the application. On top of this, each application if given a signal to gracefully exit upon shutdown, there is no need for any extra handling of this event. Keep this in mind when coding around shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Even though following links are for Windows Vista, it may give you some pointers:

1. [How to block/cancel standby/hibernate operation in Windows Vista](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/93616/How-to-block-cancel-standby-hibernate-operation-in)
2. [How to prevent hibernate/suspend on a desktop in Vista](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/385c3b38-fb74-4bb8-b064-c2392c8f46d0/how-to-prevent-hibernatesuspend-on-a-desktop-in-vista?forum=csharpgeneral)